# jfreechart: different setItemMargin() within Category possible?

Tags: jfreechart

I need to have different spacing within one category.
The arrows show where there's supposed to be a spacing.
I used `setItemMargin()` on the renderer, but the different colored "couples" need to be separate.

[alt text http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1144075/Bildschirmfoto%202010-07-26%20um%2019.20.54.JPG](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1144075/Bildschirmfoto%202010-07-26%20um%2019.20.54.JPG)

Answer (score 1):

The relevant geometry is defined by the various `calculate*()` methods in [`BarRenderer`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/category/BarRenderer.html#getItemMargin%28%29), which you can override in your implementation of `AsymmetricStatisticalBarRenderer`.

Comment: I tried to override the calculateSeriesWidth() method but it seems to be never used by my renderer? added @override annotation as well.

Comment: @tzippy: Yes, it's called by `calculateBarW0()`, which will have to be overridden as well.